# HTML DOM and strpos

Tags: php

I am using simple html dom parser

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    //produce results
    if(strpos($element, 'string')) {
       $myarray[] = $element->href;
    }
}
```

vs

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    //not producing result
    if(strpos($element->href, 'string')) {
       $myarray[] = $element->href;
    }
}
```

Why when i add strpos function to element->href, it never detect the word string even tho the href has string keyword.

Comment: Any chance you could post the some of the HTML that you're parsing (particularly the bit with the href's in question)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strpos('monkey', 'm')` will return `0`. `0` will be seen as false by PHP. If `$element->href` starts with `string`, it will not go inside the if.

Use

```
strpos(..., ...) === false
```

or

```
strpos(..., ...) !== false
```

Comment: ahhh i found why, i tried === true hence the same, so it should be !== false where its working perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Sjoerd has mentioned (do strict equality testing), the problem might be that you're passing an object into strpos, instead of a string. This should work:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
   //not producing result
   if(strpos( (string) $element->href, 'string') !== false) {
      $myarray[] = $element->href;
   }
}
```